# Focus-in and Focus-out 'active' class add/remove behavior

Tags: jquery, class, onfocus, focusout

I have a function to add and remove the "active" class according to the behavior focus/click in a certain "input" class when focusin adds the class, when clicking outside it should remove it but it doesn't do it.

```
var inptxt = $('.form-component.input-text input')
$(inptxt').on('focusin', 
   function(){
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   }).on('focusout', function(){
     $(this).parent().removeClass('active');

  });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code is correct. Just a few syntax errors in your code**

> ```
>  inptxt = $('.form-component.input-text input')  //  ;  end with semicolumn 
>
>  $(inptxt')        //replace with $(inptxt)
> ```

```js
var inptxt = $('.form-component.input-text input');
$(inptxt).on('focusin', 
   function(){
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   }).on('focusout', function(){
     $(this).parent().removeClass('active');

  });
```

```css
div.active {
  background-color:rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-component input-text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic appears to work fine.  Is there something missing from your question that identifies the issue?

```js
$('.form-component.input-text input').on('focus', 
   function(){
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   }).on('focusout', function(){
     $(this).parent().removeClass('active');

  });
```

```css
div.active {
  background-color:rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-component input-text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Taplar

I replace the $selector with a variable and now the function works fine!! I'm using the jquery-3.3.1 version.

I have no idea what could have been wrong  :/